# Down pointing arrow CSS3

Tags: css

I'm trying to create an object like this using CSS3:

[image]

Basically this is a down pointing arrow (the blue part). Tried several services such as http://www.cssarrowplease.com/ but they don't produce quite what's needed.

Any clues how such arrows can be made?

```css
.arrow_box {
  position: relative;
  background: #88b7d5;
}

.arrow_box:after {
  top: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  border: solid transparent;
  content: " ";
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  position: absolute;
  pointer-events: none;
  border-color: rgba(136, 183, 213, 0);
  border-top-color: #88b7d5;
  border-width: 30px;
  margin-left: -30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="arrow_box"></div>
```

Comment: What's the css you got generated?

Comment: @Filburt I've updated my question with the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use multiple background and gradient like this:

```css
body {
  margin:0;
  height:100vh;
  background:
    linear-gradient(blue,blue) top/100% 50px,
    linear-gradient(to bottom left,blue 49%,transparent 50%) 0 50px/50.1% 100px,
    linear-gradient(to bottom right,blue 49%,transparent 50%) 100% 50px/50.1% 100px,
    #000;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

You can also rely on border to make the background less complex:

```css
.box {
  height:100vh;
  border-top:50px solid blue;
  background:
    linear-gradient(to bottom left,blue 49%,transparent 50%) top left,
    linear-gradient(to bottom right,blue 49%,transparent 50%) top right,
    #000;
  background-size:50.1% 40%;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}

body {
  margin:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could set the `background` to one color and implement a triangle that points down, like this:

```css
#triangle-down {
 width: 0;
 height: 0;
 border-left: 55px solid transparent;
 border-right: 55px solid transparent;
 border-top: 125px solid blue;
  background: black;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
</head>
<body>

 <p id="triangle-down"></p>

</body>
</html>
```

Obviously, this is a basic example that you can tweak to meet your particular needs.
For more examples, I suggest visiting [this](https://css-tricks.com/examples/ShapesOfCSS/) site. I hope this was helpful.

Comment: Thanks. The thing is that it should be fluid width, not fixed. That is my concern.

Answer (score 0):

You can consider using pseudo code. The example below will look good on small devices. For larger devices a [media query](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries) needs to be defined using different settings.

```css
body {
margin: 0;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: black;
  height: 200px;
  position:relative;
}

.container:before {
  content: "";
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 600px solid transparent;
  border-right: 600px solid transparent;
  border-top: 160px solid darkblue;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: -250px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container"></div>
```